# Filter dynamic html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery Searchable Plugin to filter data on a table. It works when table is loaded in html. When I create table dynamically with jQuery, the plugin is not working. I tried to reset plugin after creating table but it is still not working. 
I append `<tr>` and `<td>` elements dynamically to the table. After append in the browser source it shows table empty.    `<tbody id="dataTable">   </tbody>`

What should I do in such case when I create elements dynamically? Does not jQuery reach the dynamic data or elements? Or is it about Searchable plugin?

Comment: did you check the plugins documentation..? does it support dynamic tables..?

Comment: Post the script you are using.

Comment: There is not any comment about dynamic tables in documentation. My question is not about the plugin but also about dynamic elements. In such case; does jQuery reach dynamic elements? Script is here: http://bit.ly/1lCyXGl

Answer (score 1):

I think this plugin will help you

for table search
http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

for table sort
http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html

Comment: It seems OK. But still I wonder how to reach dynamic data with jQuery. I will try this plugin.